# Amazing families of algorithms over implicit graphs

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, graph-theory, dynamic-programming

Dynamic programming is, almost by definition, to find a shortest/longest path on an implicit dag.
Every DP algorithm just does this.

An [Holographic algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holographic_algorithm) can be loosely described as something that counts perfect matchings in implicit planar graphs.

So, my question is: are there any other families of algorithms that use well-known algorithms over implicit graphs to achieve a considerable speedup?

Comment: Maybe this question is better suited for a community wiki...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optimisation problems for which a greedy algorithm always gives an optimal solution have [matroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid#Greedy_algorithms) structure.  A matroid is a set system, so it's more general than a graph (which is a set system in which the subsets (called edges) all have exactly 2 elements) but it might still be of interest to you.

Holographic algorithms look very interesting and I haven't heard of them before -- will definitely take a look!

Comment: So a greedy algorithm finds a maximum weight independent set of an implicit matroid (or more generally a special greedoid or accesible set system)! I find all of this very beautiful.

Comment: That sounds about right... :)  Also I appreciate your marking my answer "correct" but you might want to just +1 me instead -- marking an answer "correct" so early on might discourage other answerers.

Answer (score 3):

Another idea that comes to mind is **polyhedral optimisation**.  Basically, [linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) is an efficient way to solve optimisation problems involving linear inequalities and continuous variables, but restricting the variables to the integers leads to an NP-hard optimisation problem in general.  That's unfortunate because a huge variety of problems can be expressed as integer programming problems.

The usual approach has been to exhaustively enumerate all feasible solutions and select the best, possibly using [branch and bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) to prune parts of the search space which cannot be optimal.  That can sometimes work quite well, but the newer polyhedral approach is often dramatically better.

The method that I understand the best is the [cutting-plane method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting-plane_method), in which a linear relaxation of the problem is solved (using e.g. the simplex algorithm); if the solution happens to be integral, we have the answer for the integer restriction of the problem too.  If it's not, then a plane is sought which separates the found non-integral solution from the feasible region of integer solutions.  This plane is then added to the problem as a constraint, and the new problem is solved using linear programming again.  This continues until an integral solution is produced.

Clearly such a plane must exist; further, a [general-purpose algorithm exists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting-plane_method#Gomory.27s_cut) for finding them (although it's performance is usually very weak).  Researchers have devoted a lot of time to finding better algorithms for solving this "separation problem" for specific problem types.  The most famous example is the Travelling Salesman Problem, where the [increase in computationally feasible problem size is nothing less than staggering](http://www.tsp.gatech.edu/history/pictorial/pictorial.html).

The cutting planes approach achieves better performance by limiting the number of constraints simultaneously under consideration; an alternative approach is [column generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed_column_generation), in which the number of variables simultaneously being optimised is limited.

Not sure if this really fits your criteria of an implicit graph algorithm, but it's certainly a fascinating non-obvious approach I think!